# DBT Cloud do not automatically update references when I rename a model

Tags: model, reference, dbt

In a DBT Cloud project
I use references to my models.
But when I rename a model by changing the file name, DBT Cloud do not automatically update references and I ve to do a DBT Build to see the errors and update them 1by1.
Is there a better way to perform model renaming so it propagates automatically ?

I run a DBT Build, and get errors for the references

Comment: AFAIK, the DBT IDE does not support refactoring renaming models. When I have to do this, or any other global project search/replace, I load up my project in PyCharm and do it there. Not ideal, but it does what I need it to do.